# Matters with the eZURLAliasFilterAppendNodeID

Tags: ezpublish, google-news

I have to use the eZURLAliasFilterAppendNodeID class, which modify the url_alias of all the nodes from the given classes and append their node_id at the end.

The matter is that I need to append the date of the node's creation too and it seems that neither eZURLAliasFilterAppendNodeID and ezURLAlias do the job.

Does someone see a way to do that, please ? I haven't found any class which could, but I don't really want to add some code in my system classes... :-S

Thank's !

--
John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a look at the default site.ini file :

```
# List of active filters, each entry must contain the name of the class
# which implements the filtering.
# DEPRECATED, use FilterClasses instead
Filters[]

# List of classes you want to call as an eZURLALiasFilter
FilterClasses[]
FilterClasses[]=eZURLAliasFilterAppendNodeID
```

This basically means that you can develop your own filter since eZ Publish lets you tell him what PHP classes are called when generating an URL :

### 1. Create a new php class in extension/yourextension/classes/ezurlaliasfilterappenddate.php

```php
class eZURLAliasFilterAppendDate extends eZURLAliasFilter
{
    public function __construct() {}

    public function process( $text, &$languageObject, &$caller )
    {
        if( !$caller instanceof eZContentObjectTreeNode )
        {
            eZDebug::writeError( 'The caller variable was not an eZContentObjectTreeNode', __METHOD__ );
            return $text;
        }

        $separator  = eZCharTransform::wordSeparator();
        $publishedTimestamp = $caller->attribute( 'object' )->attribute( 'published' )
        $formattedDate = ....
        $text .= $separator . $formattedDate;

        return $text;
    }
}
```

Note : you might have to implement the same test on the class_identifier that is done in `eZURLAliasFilterAppendNodeID` if you don't want to choose which content classes will be concerned

### 2. Configure it in your site.ini.append.php override

probably in settings/siteaccess/yourfrontendsite/site.ini.append.php

```
[URLTranslator]
FilterClasses[]=eZURLAliasFilterAppendDate
```

### 3. Regenerate the php autoloads for your extensions : `php bin/php/ezpgenerateautoloads.php -e`

Comment: Thanks for your help. I don't think that there are better solutions to this issue.
I implemented as the way you and it works perfectly, whithout modifying previously existant code.

Comment: Glad to see it helped :)
Don't forgot to mark/rate the answer.